# Merging datasets based on date column

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion

Hello Stack Community,

I am trying to merge two datasets based on the date column in each.
Below are the snapshots of each dataset, in which, you can clearly see that date column only is formatted as year-month-day, with no specification for hour:minute:second.

[dataset 1; snapshot of date column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzwPS.png)

[dataset 2; snapshot of date column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjeCs.png)

I am merging the two datasets using the following code:

`final <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by.x="close_date", by.y = "date",all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)`

Below is another snapshot which shows the result of the code above. As you can see, somehow the hour:minute:second appears in date column which dirsputs the merge.

[result of the merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6noM.png)

Is there a way to merge the two columns properly? Maybe someone could suggest the function that would set hh:mm:ss to 00:00:00? Btw, beforehand in the script I have both columns "close_date" from dataset1 and "date" from dataset2 formatted in the same way using the `as.POSIXct` function.

You can check the R output for head() below:

```
 head(dataset1) %>%
   select(close_date)
 
 A tibble: 6 x 1
  close_date         
  <dttm>             
1 2020-03-01 00:00:00
2 2020-03-02 00:00:00
3 2020-03-03 00:00:00
4 2020-03-04 00:00:00
5 2020-03-05 00:00:00
6 2020-03-06 00:00:00


 head(dataset2) %>%
   select(date)

 A tibble: 6 x 1
  date               
  <dttm>             
 1 2020-03-01 00:00:00
 2 2020-03-02 00:00:00
 3 2020-03-03 00:00:00
 4 2020-03-04 00:00:00
 5 2020-03-05 00:00:00
 6 2020-03-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: I suspect the two date columns actually have different time zones. You will need to provide the output of `dput(head(dataset1))` and `dput(head(dataset2))` in order for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the provided data (in future please provide data directly with `dput(head(dataset1))`. See here [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

We could define the date format in each dataset before merging using `ymd` function of `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

dataset1$close_date <- ymd(dataset1$close_date)
dataset2$date <- ymd(dataset2$date)

final <- merge(dataset1, dataset2, by.x="close_date", by.y = "date",all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
final
```

```
  close_date    coin case_count_world_
1 2020-03-01 BTCUSDT                  
2 2020-03-02 BTCUSDT                  
3 2020-03-03 BTCUSDT                  
4 2020-03-04 BTCUSDT                  
5 2020-03-05 BTCUSDT                  
6 2020-03-06    <NA>                  
7 2020-03-07    <NA>                  
8 2020-03-08    <NA>
```

data:

```
dataset1 <- structure(list(close_date = structure(c(18322, 18323, 18324, 
18325, 18326), class = "Date"), coin = c("BTCUSDT", "BTCUSDT", 
"BTCUSDT", "BTCUSDT", "BTCUSDT")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

dataset2 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 
18326, 18327, 18328, 18329), class = "Date"), case_count_world_ = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion about head() and for the provided solution. ymd() works well.